# Zxing android embeddedでの、バーコード読み取り部分の変更

Tags: android

Android開発初心者です。

Zxingを利用して、バーコードリーダーを作ろうと思っております。
Githubのサンプル等を見て作っているのですが、バーコードの読み取り部分の変更(定義)方法がわかりません。ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

やりたいこととしては、カメラは全画面表示にして、その中で、バーコード読み取り部分を一部に限定したいと思っております。

Comment: 解決したなら回答の横のチェックマークを押して承認してください。(と言っても最近ログインしてないみたいだけど）

Answer (score 1):

・Activityをカスタマイズしてカメラ領域を表示したい場合
参考：http://osa030.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/10/14/190350
・ライブラリで提供されるActivityを呼び出してonActivityResultで読み取り結果を取得したい場合
参考：http://qiita.com/alingogo/items/3006e5685057c23db6bd

ちなみにaarファイルが必要になる場合はaarファイルをAndroidStudioで生成してライブラリとして取り込む必要があります。[Android Studioでローカルのaarファイルを使ったプロジェクトを作成]で検索

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
こちらの説明が足りていなかったのですが、カメラの中の読み取り部分の、位置
やサイズを変更したいと考えております。

「osa030」のサイトの「CompoundBarcodeViewへの細かいデコードオプション指
定は今のところIntent経由じゃないとできない」の部分が上記の質問に該当する
のでしょうか？

Comment: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/b189fd1d5629770b1ecbdf3e2f55a37776538957/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/ViewfinderView.java
を見ると、cameraManagerからRectのサイズをとってきているように見えます。  


https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/b189fd1d5629770b1ecbdf3e2f55a37776538957/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.java
の  `         int width = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.WIDTH, 0);
          int height = intent.getIntExtra(Intents.Scan.HEIGHT, 0);` 
がfinderViewの高さを設定していると思うのでおそらくIntentでこの値を渡すと変更可能ではないかと思います。    
ZXingTestActivity.javaの143行目あたりで実際に使っているコードが見られますね。

Comment: ちなみにカメラ起動時に遅延がありますので、ボタン連打でActivity呼び出せるようにすると、ボタンを連打するとカメラがクラッシュして再起動するまで使えなくなるので気を付けてください。

Comment: すみません上はjourneyapps/zxing-android-embeddedについてではないですね。本家のをそのまま使う場合でした。
journeyapps/zxing-android-embeddedだと使えないですね。https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/issues/116
 からするとhttps://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/tree/3.x#customization を見ればよいようですが、あとは自分でやってみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！これですね！どうもありがとうございました！